# null value in column "id" of relation "user" violates not-null constraint

Tags: java

I am trying for like 4 hours now without managing to fix an issue
I have a front end registration form , this is the code:

````
                          <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 mb-4">
                              <div class="form-outline">
                                <input type="text" id="form3Example1" name="firstName" class="form-control" />
                                <label class="form-label" for="form3Example1">First name</label>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 mb-4">
                              <div class="form-outline">
                                <input type="text" id="form3Example2" name="lastName" class="form-control" />
                                <label class="form-label" for="form3Example2">Last name</label>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
          
                          <div class="form-outline mb-4">
                            <input type="email" id="form3Example3" name="email" class="form-control" />
                            <label class="form-label" for="form3Example3">Email address</label>
                          </div>
          
                          <div class="form-outline mb-4">
                            <input type="password" id="form3Example4" name="password" class="form-control" />
                            <label class="form-label" for="form3Example4">Password</label>
                          </div>
          
                          
          
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block mb-4 show">
                            Sign up
                          </button>
          
                        </form> ```
````

then i have in intellij the following:
- RegistrationController class

````
    
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.ui.Model;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
    
    import java.util.Collections;
    
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/register")
    public class RegistrationController {
    
        @Autowired
        private UserRepository userRepository;
    
        @GetMapping
        public String registerForm(Model model) {
            model.addAttribute("user", new User());
            return "";
        }
    
        @PostMapping
        public String registerSubmit(User user) {
            userRepository.save(user);
            return "/index.html";
        }
    } ```
````

then

- User class

````
    
    import lombok.Data;
    import javax.persistence.*;
    
    import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.SEQUENCE;
    
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "user")
    @Data
    public class User {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "serial")
        private Integer id;
    
        @Column(name = "first_name")
        private String firstName;
    
        @Column(name = "last_name")
        private String lastName;
    
        private String email;
        private String password;
    } ```
````

then

- UserRepository java interface

````
    
    import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
    
    @Repository
    public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {
    
    }  ```
````

when i add the information in the registration form and hit sign up, i get the following error in intellij

````
    
    org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "id" of relation "user" violates not-null constraint
      Detail: Failing row contains (null, Paul Ciprian, Avram, timis_paul93@yahoo.ro, sdgsdg).
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2675) ~[postgresql-42.3.8.jar:42.3.8]  ```
````

this is the application.properties (i have removed username and password for obvious reasons)

````
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
server.port=8081 ```
````

and this is the pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.9</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>ro.fortech</groupId>
    <artifactId>guardianangel</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>GuardianAngel</name>
    <description>Timis Paul - Java Pre-employment Project</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.32.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.20</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.9</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>



</project>
```

and this is my postgres

[image: postgrespic]

Comment: why not just `nextval('user_id_seq')`? Like why do you need `::regclass`?

Comment: i have removed that, still the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this on your `User` entity:

```
@SequenceGenerator(name = "userIdSeq", sequenceName = "user_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
```

and this on your `id`:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "userIdSeq")
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "serial")
private Integer id;
```

Comment: same error, i've been jumping around those annotations for hours now.
Do you think i could give you access through teamviewer?

Comment: Can you manually insert a row via sql right on the database using `nextval('user_id_seq')`? You've got to break this down into the lowest logical level to find where the issue is...go as barebones as possible to find the issue...

Comment: someone fixed the issue for me, thank you for the help though, it had to do with some versions and some extra code

Comment: @PaulTimis could you post your solution? Thanks